# JQuery $(window).width() and $(window).height() return NULL only on parts of website

Tags: jquery

I have integrated in jquery code to do a simply dim out popup window when a user clicks in a form field

this works fine on our front page but when on a forums page (phpbb2 derivative) i get an error in firebug console as follows:-

$("#fuzz") is null
[Break On This Error]

$("#fuzz").css("height", $(document).height());

our code is below:-

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  

   //Adjust height of overlay to fill screen when page loads  

   $("#fuzz").css("height", $(document).height());  

   $('#clickme').focus( function() {
       $("#fuzz").fadeIn();  
      return false;         
  });      

   //When the link that triggers the message is clicked fade in overlay/msgbox  
   $(".alert").click(function(){  
      $("#fuzz").fadeIn();  
      return false;  
   });  

   //When the message box is closed, fade out  
   $(".close").click(function(){  
      $("#fuzz").fadeOut();  
      return false;  
   });  

});  

//Adjust height of overlay to fill screen when browser gets resized  
$(window).bind("resize", function(){  
   $("#fuzz").css("height", $(window).height());  
});
</script>
```

the website is http://www.motorhomefacts.com

unfortunately the search box is only displayed to members of the site, but the error is present in firebug regardless on any page within the forums i.e.

http://www.motorhomefacts.com/forums.html

We have a few other errors showing in Firebug but I am not a java coder (php ok) so any help with those would be much appreciated i.e.

Overlib error
missing ) after formal parameters
function escSglQuote(st
overlib.js (line 118, col 23)

Answer (score 0):

You have set `noConflict` somewhere in your jQuery code. jQuery has been set to use `jQuery()`, not `$()`.

Change your code to replace instances of `$` with `jQuery` and it will work, for example:

```
jQuery("#fuzz").css("height", jQuery(document).height());
```

Comment: Hard to say, but it might be better to remove the noConflict stuff to avoid future problems. However, this could, of course, cause problems right now.

Answer (score 0):

The overlib.js file seems to be truncated on this line:

```
function escSglQuote(st
```

Was there a problem with the file transfer? Perhaps your server is out of space?